# Extract nested attributes from object

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't find any questions/answers related to this that don't have to do with arrays. I have this service to retrieve a DTO from my backend:

```js
this.paymentService.createMockWireBuy(this.company.companyId, payment).subscribe((data) => {
  this.response = data;
  if(this.response.status){
    this.paymentStatus = this.response.status;
  }
});
```

The "data" being returned is wrapped in a JsonProperty called "data" (have to do this to handle the response from another service we call) like so

```java
public class TransferDtoResponse {
  @JsonProperty("data")
  private TransferDtoRequest transferDetails;
}
```

So the "data" object on the frontend ends up looking like this:

```
data: {
   data: {
    amount: {amount: "5.00", currency: "USD"}
    status: "pending"
    RefId: "123"
   }
}
```

After I assign "data" to the response variable, response.status is coming up as undefined (in the if statement) because response has that same nesting issue as above ^. How do I remove that extra "data" layer from the object? I cannot access data.data either, because "data" is technically not a field on the DTO object (as below)

This is the response class:

```js
export class TransferDtoResponse {
  constructor(
    public trackingRef?: string,
    public amount?: Balance,
    public status?: string
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not really clear. What does the data you receive in the frontend really looks like? Is it JSON? What you posted is not JSON. Also share your `createMockWireBuy` method.

Comment: My guess is that you defined `createMockWireBuy` as returning `Observable<TransferDtoResponse>` but it's not the actual return type and you are getting confused about it.

Comment: Define your DTO with the data properties, or define the result as `{ data: { data: TransferDtoResponse } }`

Comment: @GaëlJ I copied from the browser, so brackets were removed. Updated to reflect JSON.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think the latter is what I need. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `data[ "data" ]` to response variable.

Comment: I tried this and I get 'Property 'data' does not exist on type 'TransferDtoResponse'"'